# EUDRACT Pattern check

Tags: design-patterns, informatica

I want to do a pattern check in informatica(iics) preferably under CDQ than CDI
'YYYY-NNNNNN-CC

The EudraCT number has the format YYYY-NNNNNN-CC,
where: YYYY is a year after 1990.
NNNNNN is a six digit sequential number.
CC is a check digit.
For the other ones, no specific control"

I guess this cant be achieved via REGEX, Please give your expert opinions to tackle this check.

I had tried multiple REGEX options, and still pondering over to find the right appropriate approach to solve the requirement

Comment: Hi! Please show the regex patterns you've tried and tell what is the issue with those. I'm sure we'll figure this out!